# How to access all JSON array name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

Here I am trying to access the json data via an AJAX call. My JSON data looks like this:

```
{
    "abhinav": {
        "signup_date_time": "2017-01-27 22:01:45",
        "package_id": "2",
        "total_leads": 0
    },
    "abitcorp": {
        "signup_date_time": "2016-09-10 06:14:46",
        "package_id": "2",
        "total_leads": 0
    },
    "abstech": {
        "signup_date_time": "2015-12-01 11:30:01",
        "package_id": "2",
        "total_leads": 0
    },
    "acccenture": {
        "signup_date_time": "2016-12-19 12:25:18",
        "package_id": "2",
        "total_leads": 0
    },
    "accops": {
        "signup_date_time": "2016-04-15 00:16:50",
        "package_id": "2",
        "total_leads": 0
    },
    "acmeeventsindia": {
        "signup_date_time": "2016-10-06 05:16:18",
        "package_id": "2",
        "total_leads": 0
    }
}
```

Here I want to access the name alone. How to do that? Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Comment: This isn't a valid json document.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: What do you mean with "*access the name alone*"? If you want to loop thru that object, use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: @rmlan what's wrong with it?

Comment: @charlietfl Prior to an edit (not by OP, mind you), there were no opening braces. The document started with a key.